# Powershell jobs & variables

Tags: powershell

How i can get vars from a jobs? Something like that:

```
$Var=72
$Job=start-job -Name Test {$b=8;$a=777;while($true){$a+=1;sleep 1}}

$sum=(Receive-Job $Job).a + $Var

write-host $sum

Write-Host (Receive-Job $Job).b
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-7#examples) for `Start-Job` yet?

Comment: You won't be able to do that without attaching a debugger to the process hosting the job. If you want help with an actual job (that doesn't contain an infinite loop), please update the code sample :)

Comment: Theo, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would output `$i` every second:

```
start-job { for ($i = 0; $i -lt 10; $($i++;sleep 1)) {$i} } | receive-job -wait -auto

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Start-ThreadJob has an undocumented -StreamingHost parameter:

```
Start-ThreadJob { write-host hi } -StreamingHost $host

Id Name  PSJobTypeName State      HasMoreData Location   Command
-- ----  ------------- -----      ----------- --------   -------
11 Job11 ThreadJob     NotStarted False       PowerShell  write-host hi

PS C:\Users\js> hi
```